# Physics of throwing a power cord into a swimming pool

Tags: electricity, water, conductors

I saw a few questions related to swimming pools so I figured out I may ask here.

If one takes a power cord that's plugged into a wall socket on one end and throws the other end in a bath, it may kill the person in the bath.

If one takes a power cord that's plugged into a wall socket on one end and throws the other end in the ocean, it's obviously not going to kill all the person in all the oceans worldwide.

Where's the cutoff? For example if I'm in my pool here at home and my kiddo plugs and then throws an extension cord in the pool, full of regular water (not low conductivity one), is it likely to kill me? What if I'm standing at the other side the pool?

What'd be the 10 000 feet of the physics involved?

Comment: (*) btw I'm forty and this is definitely not homework

Comment: You should be able to work it out yourself. (And know better about the dangers, inquisitive kids read these pages.....: )  The power goes to split the water. So how much power does a hydrogen cell use and scale it accordingly. Locally I would say it heats the water up, but not on the large scale you propose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cutoff is in a place you don't want to be.  I highly recommend not searching for that cutoff.

What will happen when you throw the end of the cord into the water is that you're going to create a giant parallel resistor problem with all the different paths the electricity can take.  This includes not only the paths from one prong of the cord to the other, but also paths which go from the hot wire to a grounded object (like the plumbing of the bathtub) through the ground, and back to the neutral line at the shunt you find between ground and neutral in a circuit breaker box.

The electricity will flow more through paths of low resistance.  Most of the current will go straight from one prong to the other.  Unfortunately, that leaves all the rest of the current that doesn't take that path.  It takes all sorts of paths, some of which are through the person.  It turns out it doesn't take much current at all to stop a heart ([100mA is a common number](https://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~p616/safety/fatal_current.html)).  Rather than have people do a bunch of electrical engineering problems to decide whether it is safe to throw a cord into a bathtub, we instead give the common sense answer of "don't!"

So will it kill you in the pool?  The answer is to not do the math and say "it depends... so don't do it."  However, you could do calculations based on the different paths the current could take, and the amperage rating on the circuit breaker.  When doing so, you'll also have to take into account transient issues like the capacitance of the cable and the dynamic behavior of the circuit breaker and all sorts of uncomfortable things like that.  When GFCI's are designed, the engineers go through all that math so that you don't have to.  If you think your kids might throw a power line into the pool, install GFCI's on all nearby outlets.  Their job is to interrupt the current before it can kill a human.  *(Then you might want to re-evalulate your life choices, given the kids you just raised!  Just sayin')*

This also scales well.  This is why lightning can hit the ocean dozens of times a second across the world, and you don't get electrocuted, but you *really* shouldn't be swimming anywhere near a lightning storm.  Take the same calculations you did on your 15A circuit breaker, and now do them on a 30,000A lightning strike.  Same game, new odds.  Same result: "don't" =)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP was asking this question in the hope of learning some physics, not to help him decide whether to  throw a power cord in his pool.

Comment: @WillO I couldn't agree completely with that, Unfortunately  it's not the OP that would be doing the throwing, despite the genuine curiosity of the question.

Comment: @WillO That's why I referred to the parallel resistor network and the capacitance of the cable.  There's equations that can be researched.  Unfortunately, the values to plug into those equations are so varied that even with the equations, it's hard to tell what happens in any scenario.  And, as an added legal bonus, if I don't actually print the equations, I can't get them wrong and get some fool killed when they find the cutoff point and test it! =)

Comment: @Cort Ammon: (and everybody who commented).  Thanks a lot for this answer, it's very interesting  I'll see with my electrician if he can install more GFCI on the setup here (there are some, but I'm not sure the barn next to the pool is protected well enough).

Comment: GFCI? You should not use acronyms without explaining what they mean.